# Recommendation? New class (xib) or new View in a class

Tags: ios, objective-c

This question is in relation to X-code, ios, objective-c

Can anyone kindly suggest what is recommended in terms of having a new class or just additional views within exiting class for each new screen I require.

I understand that each approach has its own pros and cons in terms of flexibility in implementation, but wanted to understand if the approaches make any difference in how the app perform or.. is there a recommended way of doing things.

Thanks a lot in advance

Adding an example, as the question was suggested to be too vague.

If I wanted to add a T&C page to my login screen, what is recommended, should I simply add a 'View' to my login class, or should I create a new class 'T&C' (T&C maybe a very simple example, but I think that kind of gives the idea)

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer, too vague, too broad, no idea what you want to do, what these new classes are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your general question, the answer is "it depends..."

But for your T&C example, I would create a new view controller to be presented onscreen. Since you may end up needing that T&C content elsewhere in the app (e.g., and About screen), that would be the approach I'd take.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, so what you are suggesting is ease of implementation dictates the approach. Is there no recommendation based on
- App Performance
- IPA Size
- Any other factor?

Comment: Generally size and performance are not concerns with something like a simple VC that displays text and maybe some images. If your designs dictate the T&C be in their own screen, a view controller is definitely the answer. If they need to be a sibling view to your login (which I wouldn't suggest) you could keep it in a separate view/class so it can be reused. In many cases, with canned text like this, I'll format everything in an HTML document to my liking and load it in a web view.

Comment: thanks a lot Cameron, that answers my question.